# Cassandra timeout error for keyspaces for heavy load

Tags: amazon-keyspaces

Getting below error - Cassandra timeout during SIMPLE write query at consistency LOCAL_QUORUM (2 replica were required but only 0 acknowledged the write); nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.WriteTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during SIMPLE write query at consistency LOCAL_QUORUM (2 replica were required but only 0 acknowledged the write)

in AWS keyspaces - for one of the table below is the graph

I am using Java with AWS keyspaces . My table is using on demand capacity
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a hot key access pattern. This is denoted by the "Storage Partition Throughput exception" and the leveling out at 1,000 writes request units per second. I recommend the [following template](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-keyspaces-cloudwatch-cloudformation-templates) to help visualize Keyspaces metrics.

The service will pass these back these events to the client as a timeout exceptions. You can retry them in your application or using a retry policy in the Cassandra driver. You can use the [following policies](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-keyspaces-java-driver-helpers) to help implement exponential backoff.

You will need to determine first if your hotkey is against a single row or a single partition. Often when customers export data from Apache Cassandra it can be ordered by partition key. If loading data exported from Apache Cassandra it's best to randomize the data before loading. This will ensure that write access is evenly distributed against the table. If you're importing or exporting data I would recommend using glue. You can use the [following example](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-keyspaces-examples/tree/main/scala/datastax-v4/aws-glue/import-from-s3) to bulk load data from s3. You will see the script will shuffle the data.

```
val orderedData = sparkSession.read.format(backupFormat).load(s3bucketBackupsLocation)  

//The following command will randomize the data.    
val shuffledData = orderedData.orderBy(rand())  

shuffledData.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").mode("append").option("keyspace", keyspaceName).option("table", tableName).save()
```

In Keyspaces, rows are distributed over many "physical storage partitions". Row collections that are part of the same logical partition are likely to be grouped together on the same physical storage partition. Physical storage partition can perform up to 1,000 Write request units per second or 3,000 Read request units per second. Over time, the service will distribute row collection over many physical partitions in a process called partition splitting. Rows located on one physical partition are split where access is highest, and the rows are moved to two separate physical partitions. As a result access to the same range of rows will have twice the throughput.